# What was your most annoying website you have ever found when creating dynamic Xpaths

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

When interviewing a candidate for QA automation positions, I used to give a website URL and ask them to create a dynamic XPath for a given element.

It's mostly on https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/

But I feel the element locators are pretty much straight forward, and it's easy to create e XPath.
So I'm just looking for some websites where it is really tricky to create dynamic XPath for elements.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: What's the purpose of asking this question in an interview? What are you trying to learn from the candidate? You said yourself "it's easy to create xpath." Wouldn't a better question to ask be: "what are the different locator strategies and how do they differ? Is one more beneficial than another?"

Comment: XPath does not equal test automation. You are not getting any insight into your candidates' skills of test automation. You might want to come up with a better interview questions.

Answer (score 2):

https://www.davidmello.com/best-websites-for-practicing-test-automation/

This blog lists all amazing practice websites

One of my favorite is : http://automationpractice.com/index.php ,

try to ask for scenarios they will automate , see how will they find locator for a random item in the list and so on.

**Validate the thought process more than the final out come**

Now coming back to your Question , writing complex Xpath doesn't show someones automation skills but could show an in ability to think .

Writing simpler xpaths without using XPATH axes or XPATH itself shows more skill and familiarization with test automation and HTML DOMs .

I would prefer someone who could use `.something` instead of `//*[@class="something"]` or justify why they didnt

Answer (score 1):

> “Talk is cheap. Show me the code.” - Linus Torvalds

#### How about evaluating their coding & logical thinking skills instead ?

By a series of small from easy to moderate range of questions in a given language which will be used in automation role.

Each should be coded easily in less than 5 mins by any average coder.

> The trick is to start from basics. You will be surprised to know how
> many candidates cannot reverse a string on paper with correct syntax and it just takes 5 mins to find out.

Sample questions:

- Find the highest frequency letter in a given string. "highest" --> h:2
- Find & remove the duplicate letters in a given string. "duplicate" --> "duplicate" ( duplicate does not have duplicate letters!!)
- Reverse a given string of digits to a number. "524" --> 524
- Reverse the order of words in a string but not the words themselves. --> "themselves words the not but string a in words of order the reverse"

And so on..

> Once they wrote the code ask them to test it and find a edge case to
> break their own code!

Find & remove the duplicate letters in a given string. "duplicate" --> "duplicate"

"duplicate" string input  is good edge test case for testing as it does not have duplicate letters!!   and should be returned as is if code is correct.

> So this way you tested their testing skills as well.

Sample website to get ideas...
https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/examples

https://www.w3resource.com/java-exercises/basic/index.php

If somebody can think logically on their feet and code a moderate random coding problem in an upfront interview situation on paper , I think he would be either knowing how to write locators or he can find out easily as and when needed.

However  on the other hand  someone who cannot code an easy problem will have a hard time working in test automation role in general.And more importantly questionably ever worked in automation in the first place.

I think the core problem is to find out between candidates who can code easily or who can't.